# Admob interstitial ad not showing in Android app: ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

i have a problem using admob interstitial ads.i have done some searching and all i can find is that the error code that i am getting (code 3, the no fill error) means that there are no available ads to display. some say that ads will start appearing after a couple of hours but it has been a few days now and still ads are not appearing.

as far as i know i have set it up correctly. it works when i use the test ads but not when i use my live app id.

using the live app id on a real device returns ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL in the AdListener's onAdFailedToLoad() method but displays a test ad on the emulator. Nothing is displayed when the published app is installed from the google play store.

how can i get ads to display? or does this mean that ads will never be displayed

Comment: can you try with different AD_UNIT_ID? found similar issue resolved after using different AD_UNIT_ID? Also share type of app in app store. Usually Design for families or app designed for children get lot of such failures

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will try that. It's an app about addiction (see here on google play - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=idig.za.net.addiction)

Comment: i tried your app, didn't saw any advertisements either

Comment: solved the problem, turns out i am an idiot! i used the app id instead of the ad unit id! it's working now. thanks for the tip to create a new ad unit as this got me to realise the error. thanks

Comment: don't worry.. we all make mistakes .. that's how we learn :)